# valueOf of a Integer

Tags: integer

We suppose that the method given

```
 public static Integer getVal()
     {
         return 10;
     }
```

And,

```
getVal().valueOf(12);
```

we know that it return 12 ?

WHY does it return 12 ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it ? And which language are we talking about ?

Comment: It would even return `12` when `getVal()` returns `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Interger.valueOf() is a static method.

Comment: +1. And you should be getting a compiler warning about this, too. Don't call static methods on instances.